# Selecting single row out of multiple ones

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my SQL query

```
SELECT 
    a.recordID b.recordState
FROM
    RecordTable a
INNER JOIN 
    RecordStateTable b ON a.recordID = b.recordID
```

The output of this query is

```
RecordID      RecordState
--------------------------
record1       passed
record2       passed
record3       passed
record3       failed
record4       passed
```

In the result I am getting two values for **record3** i.e passed and failed. I want to discard such rows that has values both passed and failed and select only the failed ones.

I need to get only `record1`, `record2`, `record4` in my final result. I don't want `record3` because it contains both values passed and failed.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s apologies I am very new to SQL.I'll update that right away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several ways, one is using `GROUP BY`:

```
select RecordID, max(RecordState)
from RecordTable a
inner join RecordStateTable b
    on a.recordID = b.recordID
group by RecordID
```

Will work because passed > failed.

Comment: I didnt knew we could use max comparision for passed and failed.That's so interesting

Comment: `MAX()` works on the ASCII table and translate chars into numerical values. `B > A` as `2 > 1` @Rohit

Answer (score 0):

Your `JOIN` is unnecessary.  The simplest way to write your query is:

```
SELECT rst.recordID, MAX(rst.recordState) as recordState
FROM RecordStateTable rst
GROUP BY rst.recordID;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases that are abbreviations for the tables.  This makes it easier to read the queries.
- You need a `GROUP BY`.
- The `JOIN` is unnecessary because `recordID` is in the same table as `recordState`.